# SQLite Android: insert data failing "NOT NULL constraint failed: call_table.ID for last record"

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to store contact info in SQLite table but

Thi is how I am creating the table:

```
 private static final String SQL_CREATE_QUERY = "create table " + CONTACT_TABLE +
            "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , " +
            NUMBER_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
            CALL_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
            CALLER_NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
            " ) ";
```

But when I try to store 178 records it fail on the last record

```
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NUMBER_COLUMN, callerInforToInsert.getCallerNumber());
    contentValues.put(CALL_TIME_COLUMN, callerInforToInsert.getCallTime());
    contentValues.put(CALLER_NAME_COLUMN, callerInforToInsert.getCallerName());
    long result = writableDatabase.insert(CONTACT_TABLE , null, contentValues);
    writableDatabase.close();
    Log.w(TAG, "Inserted " + result);
```

It throws constraint exception that ID is null. But I am auto-incrementing ID I am not assigning manually.

```
                                                              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: call_table.ID (code 1299)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
                                                                  at com.rasfi.ai.domain.engine.DataBaseHelper.insertRow(DataBaseHelper.java:94)
                                                                  at com.rasfi.ai.domain.engine.DataBaseHelper.insertList(DataBaseHelper.java:114)
                                                                  at com.rasfi.ai.ui.fragment.CallsRecordingsFragment$WorkLoadHandler.doInBackground(CallsRecordingsFragment.java:126)
                                                                  at com.rasfi.ai.ui.fragment.CallsRecordingsFragment$WorkLoadHandler.doInBackground(CallsRecordingsFragment.java:105)
                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Take out the "NOT NULL" in the create table. I think its pointless anyway since its autoincrement

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Room API

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = ID_COLUMN)
private int id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is very likely due to the SQL for the table create being incorrect. You have a suprious comma **`,`** after the last column.

Instead of :-

```
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_QUERY = "create table " + CONTACT_TABLE +
        "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , " +
        NUMBER_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
        CALL_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
        CALLER_NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT , " + //<<<<< , = ouch
        " ) ";
```

try :-

```
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_QUERY = "create table " + CONTACT_TABLE +
        "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , " +
        NUMBER_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
        CALL_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT , " +
        CALLER_NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT " +
        " ) ";
```

Obviously you'll need to ensure that the table is dropped and created. It would probably be easiest to delete the App's data or uninstall the App. Unless you have data that needs to be kept, in which case you would have to ascertain how to keep the data (`ALTER` to rename the table perhaps).

As per the comments `NOT NULL` is superfluous and there is also the high chance that `AUTOINCREMENT` is also superfluos as per :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed. [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The use of INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will give you a generally increasing unique id (not guaranteed as when you've hit 9223372036854775807, it would use unused numbers, as AUTOINCREMENT guarantees a higher number when 9223372036854775807 is reached it will issue an SQLITE_FULL exception rather than use an unused number.)

The additional resouces incurred when you use `AUTOINCREMENT` are centered around SQLIte creating an additional table, namely **sqlite_seqeunce**, in which it stores the last generated rowid (id) on a per table basis (2 columns **name** (table name)  and **seq** (sequence number).